# Jquery checkbox click issue

Tags: jquery

I have a check box on my form with id="chkBold". When i click or check this checkbox, i want element

to change color.
Here is my code and entire page.
It does not change color. Can you see what is wrong here?

Thanks.

```
(function () {
    $("#chkBold").click(function(){
        if($("#chkBold").is(':checked')) {
            $("p").css('color', 'Blue'); 
        }else{
            $("p").css('color', 'Red'); 
        }
     });
});


 jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/netten/dAesw/
```

Comment: add the html part please

Comment: shareef, i tried t oadd html part but it is giving formatting issues.

Comment: it's here = [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Here is my html code :http://jsfiddle.net/netten/dAesw/

Comment: And it's working if you remove all the strangeness - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dAesw/7/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dAesw/6/ Should work after being cleaned up.

Comment: It is working now if i remove all the cleanup. Marking adeneo's post as answer as yours was first. thanks

Comment: Hi all, Instead of in a script tag at the bootom of the page, i tried to create a myjqueryfile.js and included my function there. Then, i included the myjqueryfile.js file in the contentplaceholder. It does not seem to work. I tried to post a new question and it sasy the question does not meet the standards. Any idea how to getit working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a dollar sign :

```
$(function () {
    $("#chkBold").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("p").css('color', 'blue'); 
        }else{
            $("p").css('color', 'red'); 
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: @netten - did you add jQuery ?

Comment: Yes, because some other functions like button clicks etc worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check this working model ---

http://jsfiddle.net/swapnesh/Xwj6n/

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug at

```
if($("#chkBold").is(':checked'))
               {
                alert($('p'));   
                $("p").css('color', 'Blue'); 
                }
```

make sure this selector gives you the same element you want to change the color, one more thing , Do you want to change the font color or the backgroundColor, both are different.

Comment: Rupesh, it does not matter whether background or font color. All i am trying is to see that color changes on a checkbox click.

Comment: @netten ok it was just a point, I just wanted to ensure. One thing i can tell is first check the selectors you used like $("#chkBold").is(':checked'). place alerts at different locations and debug your self It will be more helpful to you in future also. Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried tidying up your jsfiddle and it seems to work...
http://jsfiddle.net/8fggu/2/